# Load SPFX webparts only after application customizer init method is completed ?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I have some webparts who have dependency of data which is obtained from application customizer.
Is it possible to load webparts after application customizer

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is use a state management approach. In React, you can use Redux or MobX (and others) as your state management solution.

So, in MobX, for example, your web part would subscribe to an observable, and when that observable changes - your data from the application customizer, for example - then your web part can grab it and do what it needs to do.

https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html

Comment: Sorry this is not what I am asking for

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements is , you want to execute your Spfx extension - oninit method after loading your other web-part or add-ins in your page .

In that case you can use timestamp (https://tecadmin.net/get-current-timestamp-in-javascript/) to record the time , how much time your data is taking to load, you can keep it in local storage .
And load your Oninit method after that time, using local storage.